# Finder method to return the last item in a collection, redis, ohm

Tags: redis, ohm

ohm provides a finder method for returning the first result, but doesn't seem to provide a similar .last finder method, is there something similar to the below for the returning the last result in a collection?

`Book.find(authors: dave.id).first`

http://ohm.keyvalue.org/Ohm/Collection.html#first-instance_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, is it doesn't, however, here is a solution:

```
Book.find(authors: dave.id).sort_by(:id, :order => "DESC").first
```